# apt-get update says "Reading package lists ... Done" and then ends the process

Tags: apt, updates

I reinstalled Ubuntu14.04 in my laptop (32 bit) since I couldn't update the system, unfortunately the problem persists. Basically when I type `sudo apt-get update`, the system search for the sources and after getting them it just says: "Reading package lists ... Done" and then ends the process.

I used to see different messages like "Building tree information" and then "Reading state information" but now nothing similar appears on the screen and the system is not updated since typing again "sudo apt-get update" gives the same result (I was expecting a message like "The system is already updated").

Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`apt-get update` only updates the package lists. You need to do `apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade the actual packages. People often combine the two as `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

**apt-get update** updates the available package index lists and is used to determine what needs to be updated on your system. It is also used to tell your system what other software is available for installing.

**apt-get upgrade** updates non-critical packages on your system based on the index. These updates typically do not require a reboot.

**apt-get dist-upgrade** updates non-critical and critical packages on your system based on the index (typically includes kernel updates). These updates typically require you to reboot afterwards for the updates to take effect (but you only need to reboot to start using those certain updates - it's not like something will break if you don't reboot right away).